# Why this function is not tail-recursive?

Tags: .net, f#, lazy-evaluation, tail-recursion

I want to read data as it's appearing in a file (the data is written by another process). Something like "continuous reading".

Simple code that just read a file to the end and finishes works without problems:

```
let readStream (r: StreamReader) =
  seq {
    while not r.EndOfStream do
      yield r.ReadLine() }
```

Now I add the following logic to it: if it reaches the end of the stream, it waits for a second, then tries again. If the data has not appeared, it sleeps for 2 seconds and so on up to 5 seconds in 5 attempts:

```
let readStream (r: StreamReader) =
    let rec loop waitTimeout waits =
        seq {
            match waitTimeout with
            | None -> 
                if not r.EndOfStream then 
                    yield r.ReadLine()
                    yield! loop None 0
                else yield! loop (Some 1000) waits
            | Some timeout when waits < 5 -> 
                let waits = waits + 1
                printfn "Sleeping for %d ms (attempt %d)..." timeout waits
                Thread.Sleep (timeout * waits)
                yield! loop None waits
            | _ -> ()
        }
    loop None 0
```

Unfortunately, it turns out to be not-tail recursive and the app crashes with StackOverflow exception quickly.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Before going into further detail, do you have generate tail calls also in debug enabled? (By default F# does not do tail calls in debug code.)

EDIT: Well, your return value is ultimately a `seq {...}` and not actually the value of `loop x y`. So you are really building up a nested sequence as opposed to using tail recursion.

Try rewriting your code in such a way, that you do not use a nested sequence, but rather use tail-recursion within the sequence.

Comment: Switching that flag in the project settings does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel points out, by definition a function with a body that's a sequence expression isn't tail recursive since any recursive calls are delayed.  This also guarantees that calling `readStream` will not cause a stack overflow - it will just return an opaque `seq<string>` value.  So the cause of the stack overflow depends at least partly on the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, your code as written works fine for me too (on F# 3.0). As `kvb` points out, is there an issue i your consumer code?

```
type Reader(k) =
    let mutable n = 0
    member __.EndOfStream = n >= k
    member __.ReadLine() = n <- n + 1; "OK"

let readStream (r: Reader) =
    let rec loop waitTimeout waits =
        seq {
            match waitTimeout with
            | None -> 
                if not r.EndOfStream then 
                    yield r.ReadLine()
                    yield! loop None 0
                else yield! loop (Some 1000) waits
            | Some timeout when waits < 5 -> 
                let waits = waits + 1
                printfn "Sleeping for %d ms (attempt %d)..." timeout waits
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeout * waits)
                yield! loop None waits
            | _ -> ()
        }
    loop None 0

let test () =
    readStream (Reader 2000000)
    |> Seq.length
```

Comment: Oh. It was my fault. You are absolutely right - the stack overflow was caused by a buggy implementation of Seq.splitEach. I'm so sorry for the misconception.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced (waitTimeout: TimeSpan option) + pattern matching with (waitTimeout: int) + if...then and the issue has gone. It works OK on seqs of several millions of elements, in constant RAM.

The bad thing is I've no idea why it works.

```
let readStream (r: StreamReader) =
    let rec loop waitTimeout waits =
        seq {
            if waitTimeout = 0<ms> then
                let line = r.ReadLine()
                if line <> null then
                    yield line
                    yield! loop 0<ms> 0
                else yield! loop 1000<ms> waits
            elif waits < 5 then
                let waits = waits + 1
                Thread.Sleep (int waitTimeout * waits)
                yield! loop 0<ms> waits
        }
    loop 0<ms> 0
```